# postgres coalesce fields, sum and group by

Tags: postgresql

maybe someone can help me out with a postgres query.

the table structure looks like this

```
  nummer   nachname   vorname   cash
 +-------+----------+----------+------+
   2       Bert       Brecht    0,758
   2       Harry      Belafonte 1,568
   3       Elvis      Presley   0,357
   4       Mark       Twain     1,555
   4       Ella       Fitz      0,333
   …
```

How can I coalesce the fields where "nummer" are the same and sum the cash values?
My output should look like this:

```
   2       Bert, Brecht      2,326
           Harry, Belafonte 
   3       Elvis, Presley    0,357
   4       Mark, Twain       1,888
           Ella, Fitz
```

I think the part to coalesce should work something like this:

```
 array_to_string(array_agg(nachname|| ', ' ||coalesce(vorname, '')), '<br />') as name,
```

Thanks for any help,

tony

Comment: Thanks for showing your effort so far, input data, and expected result. It's generally helpful if you mention your PostgreSQL version as well. As for the numbers, I'm assuming that's just some aberration of how you extracted them for display and they aren't really text strings in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  nummer, 
  string_agg(nachname||CASE WHEN vorname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', '||vorname END, E'\n') AS name,
  sum(cash) AS total_cash
FROM Table1
GROUP BY nummer;
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9b539/1); note that it doesn't display the newline characters between names, but they're still there.

The `CASE` statement is used instead of `coalesce` so you don't have a trailing comma on entries with a last name but no first name. If you want a trailing comma, use `format('%s, %s',vorname,nachname)` instead and avoid all that ugly string concatenation business:

```
SELECT
  nummer, string_agg(format('%s, %s', nachname, vorname), E'\n'),
  sum(cash) AS total_cash
FROM Table1
GROUP BY nummer;
```

If `string_agg` doesn't work, get a newer PostgreSQL, or mention the version in your questions so it's clear you're using an obsolete version. The query is trivially rewritten to use `array_to_string` and `array_agg` anyway.

If you're asking how to `sum` numbers that're actually represented as text strings like `1,2345` in the database: *don't do that*. Fix your schema. Format numbers on input and output instead, store them as `numeric`, `float8`, `integer`, ... whatever the appropriate numeric type for the job is.

Comment: hi Craig,thanks a lot for your reply. The Version is 8.4.6. Yes I get indeed an error because string_agg is not existing in this version. thus i tried array_to_string instead. this works! thanks a million.

Comment: unfortunately, I recognized an issue about that. there are rows in the db which are the same. ***f.e. 4 Mark Twain*** is 5 times the same row. is it possible to add an distinct to the name?

Comment: @tBook Sure, just use `string_agg(distinct ... )`. The same will work with `array_agg`. Try to make your sample data reflect the actual characteristics of the DB, with things like duplicates, etc. It's nice to have the table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) too, so you can see the data types.

Comment: @tBook Gah, no, you don't need to use a subquery. Just use a `distinct` filter on the aggregate.

Comment: Hi Craig, I tried for some hours know but can´t find a way. Maybe you could help me out once more. Let´s say there are to more fields in each row. see fiddle her http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/245ac/1/0. "breite" and "lange". Is it possible to sum "cash" only when the concatenate of "breitelaenge" are different in a row. what i´m looking for is a way to include "breitelaenge" in a distinct statement or something similar.

Comment: @tBook Like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/245ac/5 You don't need the subquery; use `distinct` in the aggregate expression instead for the names, and for breite/lange, add them to the `group by` expression. I very strongly recommend that you read the PostgreSQL tutorial (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html) and the rest of the documentation; you will learn a lot.